# Why are my transparent images used in a Delphi 2009 Ribbon not transparent on runtime?

Tags: image, delphi, delphi-2009, ribbon, transparent

I just played around with the new Delphi 2009 ribbon, added a few pages, groups and actionclients (large buttons) to it. I created some transparent 32x32px PNGs in Photoshop and put them into a TImageList (set to cd32bit). I added this list to the Actionmanager's Images property, to show them on the buttons.
At designtime the icons in the ribbon look just fine, but when compiling and starting the app they have a black background.
Any idea what causes this and how I can fix this? I do not want to create the images with the ribbon color as background, because I cannot switch to another colorset of the ribbon then.

Thanks in advance
Marc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Ensure that Application theme is enabled by: Project > Options > Application > Enable runtime theme.
2. Have you tried to set the DrawingStyle property of Imagelist to dsTransparent?

Comment: Thanks! You were right. "Enable runtime theme" had to be checked.
Why is this not enabled by default?

Comment: It should be enabled by default, but seems you are upgrading from older version which you have to turn it Manually

Comment: +1 Mohammed for a nice quick answer, but one minor suggestion to improve the English: "Insure" should be "Ensure that"

Comment: @sinner, don't you think you should also give Mohammed's answer an up-vote?

Comment: @Argalatyr: I am new here and have not yet earned any reputation points. I need 15 of them to up-vote the answer.
How do I get them? Do I need to answer other questions?

Comment: @Argalatyr, Thank you for the correction. 
@sinner, you can have more reputation by getting votes for your questions and answers.

Comment: @sinner: sorry - I forgot that restriction.  Happily, it no longer applies to you!

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but maybe it helps someone.

I had the same problem, and Mohammed's suggestion still didn't fix it.
It turns out you also have to set `TImageList.ColorDepth` to `cd32Bit`.

By default it's set to `cdDeviceDependent`.

[image: Object Inspector]